Jquery: replace text but skip html tag
I need to replace just the text 'Yes, I want to receive News, Discounts and Promotions'   to my custom text.
From this:
<p id="woo_ml_subscribe_field">
    <label class="checkbox ">
        <input type="checkbox" name="woo_ml_subscribe" id="woo_ml_subscribe" value="1" class="input-checkbox " checked="checked"> Yes, I want to receive News, Discounts and Promotions
   </label>
</p>

To this:
<p id="woo_ml_subscribe_field">
    <label class="checkbox ">
        <input type="checkbox" name="woo_ml_subscribe" id="woo_ml_subscribe" value="1" class="input-checkbox " checked="checked"> my custom text
   </label>
</p>

I tried with this code but it delete 'input' element which is inside the 'p' element. The input should remain after the replacement.
var content = $("#woo_ml_subscribe_field label").text().replace(' Yes, I want to receive News, Discounts and Promotions','my custom text')
    $("#woo_ml_subscribe_field label").html(content);



If you want to change text of an element then change the text of that element. Not some other element. Clarification: you say that you want to change text of element X, but in your code you explicitly select element Y

use the `.text()´ function to change the text node. That should omit any html nodes.

$("#woo_ml_subscribe_field label").text() - here you "lost" the checkbox already - the text content of any element, doesn't contain any descendant elements. You need to work with the HTML content of the element to begin with, if you want to do it this way.

a friendly suggestion... since there you would need to deal with text nodes contained in the closest parent and it would dramatically complicate the process, why don't you just embed that text content inside its own html element (span) so that you will be in the position to easily select it via id for example.. or via class once given its parent selector?

you can find the not empty TEXT_NODE and replace, like:
$('#woo_ml_subscribe_field label').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && $.trim(this.nodeValue);
}).replaceWith('your custom text');

